# Can't find document by field name

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a document like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5629aded0760cd72078b4567"),
    "name" : "Name",
    "url" : "URL.com",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2015-10-23T03:47:57.050Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2015-10-23T03:47:57.050Z")
}
```

And a function like this:

```
public function getByName($name) {
        $findQuery = array("name" => $name);
        $team = Team::find($findQuery);
        print_r($team);
        exit;
        return "Here";
    }
```

The problem is when I find by name field I alway get the empty array return. But when I try with `$findQuery = array("_id" => "5629aded0760cd72078b4567");` it's work fine.

I don't know what did I do wrong here?

Comment: make sure you use `trim($name)`, it might happen that it contains spaces.

Comment: I'm sure that the $name is correct but the result still empty. Anyway thanks for your suggest.